# Dockerfile copy folder to restore local nuget packages

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, dockerfile, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I would like to start a .NET Core WebApi in a docker container from a Unit test project. These tests will be ran during continuous integration using GitLab.
The WebApi project uses local nuget packages stored in a folder with path C:/Temp/nuget packages. This folder exists on the server which run the GitLab runner.

C:/Temp/nuget packages
C:/Users/myUser/project/MyProject with the following tree
- sln
- MyProjectWebAPI
-- dockerfile
- MyProject.Tests
-- link to the MyProjectWebAPI's dockerfile\

My dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
#copying some csproj files
RUN mkdir Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages
#VOLUME "C:/Temp/nuget packages":"Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages" -> failed, unable to name a volume in a dockerfile so my folder is empty and the dotnet restore failed
#COPY ["C:/Temp/nuget packages", "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages"]-> failed, can't reach Temp folder (using ../.. and/or finished with '/' gave the same result)
#ADD["C:/Temp/nuget packages", "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages"]-> failed, can't reach Temp folder (using ../.. and/or finished with '/' gave the same result)
#RUN cp -r "C:/Temp/nuget packages" Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages -> failed, can't reach Temp folder
RUN find Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/nugetPackages
RUN dotnet restore "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI.csproj" -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -s nugetPackages --verbosity n
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI"
RUN dotnet build "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI.dll"]
```

I have to copy C:/Temp/nuget packages in my container during the build to successfully restore nuget packages. I try several things as you can see in the dockerfile.

I run the docker build command like this

```
C:\Users\myUser\project\MyProject> docker build -t 'oncolin-webapi' --progress plain -f '.\Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI\Dockerfile' .
```

How can I achieve this ?
Is it possible to retrieve the name of the volume ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to copy my local nuget packages :

- access to the nuget packages folder of the current user (i.e. c:\users\myUser.nuget\packages) and copy my known local nuget packages (all started by "rnc" by convention) in a new folder in my solution

  ```
        var localPackagesDirPath = Path.Combine(solutionDirPath, "localNugetPackages");
        var localPackagesDir = Directory.CreateDirectory(localPackagesDirPath);

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), ".nuget", "packages"), "rnc*");
        foreach (var item in directories)
        {
            var rncDir = new DirectoryInfo(item);
            var srcRncDir = localPackagesDir.CreateSubdirectory(rncDir.Name);
            CopyAll(rncDir, srcRncDir);
        }
  ```
- copy it during build of the image
- use the local nuget packages folder to restore them

  ```
  COPY ["localNugetPackages/", "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/localNugetPackages/"]
  RUN dotnet restore "Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI/Oncolin.DataAccess.WebAPI.csproj" -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -s localNugetPackages --verbosity n
  ```

It's clearly not pretty but it's the only solution I found to achieve my goal. Luckily I don't have a lot of local nuget packages.